# TSV file with metrics-graphics.js

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js, metricsgraphicsjs

i'm trying to display a graph with data from [this](http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/estat-navtree-portlet-prod/BulkDownloadListing?file=data/tec00001.tsv.gz&unzip=true) .tsv file:

```
d3.tsv('GDP.tsv', function(data) {
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    console.log(data[i]);
}
MG.data_graphic({
    title: "Line Chart",
    description: "This is a simple line chart. You can remove the area portion by adding area: false to the arguments list.",
    data: data,          /*This is very probably part of the issue*/
    width: 240,
    height: 128,
    target: document.getElementById('graph-gdp'),
    x_accessor: 'value', /*This is very probably part of the issue*/
    y_accessor: 'time'   /*This is very probably part of the issue*/
});
```

This is outputing each row as:

```
{na_item,unit,geo\time: "B1GQ,CP_MEUR,AL", 
2005 : "6475.3 ", 
2006 : "7090.8 ", 
2007 : "7809.8 ", 
2008 : "8800.3 ", 
2009 : "8662.2 ", 
2010 : "8996.6 ", 
2011 : "9268.3 ", 
2012 : "9585.8 ", 
2013 : "9625.4 "(etc...)}
```

How would I do to display a single row, so selected with it's name ("B1GQ,CP_MEUR,AL", for example), and display that data on a graph, with x=year and y=value?

Sorry if this is a rather noobish question, but I'm new to .js, .tsv files, and web development in general. I've tried figuring this out by myself, but have been failing pathetically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you loaded that TSV using `d3.tsv`, the first step is filtering the data array, getting only that row you chose:

```
var filtered = data.filter(d => d["na_item,unit,geo\\time"] == "B1GQ,CP_EUR_HAB,AL");
//escaping the backslash here ---------------------^
```

However, since that TSV has strange headers (and values as well...), remember to escape the backslash.

That `filtered` array has only one object, and you're not going too far away with it. Thus, the next step is converting it in an array of several objects, one for each data point, using `d3.entries`:

```
var selectedData = d3.entries(filtered[0]).filter(d => d.key != ["na_item,unit,geo\\time"])
```

With that array, you can create your graph.

Here is a demo code, the array is printed in the console ("key" is the year, that you're gonna use in the x axis, and "value" is the value, that you're gonna use in the y axis):

```js
data = d3.tsvParse(d3.select("#tsv").text());
var filtered = data.filter(d => d["na_item,unit,geo\\time"] == "B1GQ,CP_EUR_HAB,AL");
var selectedData = d3.entries(filtered[0]).filter(d => d.key != ["na_item,unit,geo\\time"])
console.log(selectedData);
```

```css
pre {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<pre id="tsv">na_item,unit,geo\time 2005  2006  2007  2008  2009  2010  2011  2012  2013  2014  2015  2016 
B1GQ,CP_EUR_HAB,AL 2200  2400  2600  3000  3000  3100  3200  3300  3300  3400 p 3600 p : 
B1GQ,CP_EUR_HAB,AT 30800  32200  34000  35100  34300  35200  36800  37600  38000  38700  39400  40000 
B1GQ,CP_EUR_HAB,BE 29700  31000  32500  33100  32300  33500  34500  35100  35300  35900  36600  37400 
B1GQ,CP_EUR_HAB,BG 3100  3600  4300  5000  5000  5200  5600  5700  5800  5900 p 6300 p 6600 p</pre>
```

PS: Again, that TSV has several problems with the values.

PPS: This answer only shows you how to filter and prepare your data array, and that only.

Comment: Thanks! How would I do if the keys were, for example, 2005Q1, 2005Q2, 2005Q3? What is it in the code you've kindly provided that requires the keys to be numbers?

Comment: Right now, nothing. You'll have to create a function to transform those strange strings into numbers. Maybe, the best approach is using a regex. I suggest you post another question regarding this.